# Make an HTML form redirect to an insert or update page

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

I'm having trouble with probably something simple, but I just can't figure it out and neither can I find the answer online.

I have an HTML Form, which is used to update some user info. It is automatically populated with an Ajax livesearch. The user can then edit the info and update it.

However, I want it to redirect to an Insert into OR an Update page. I want this because if the user didn't use the livesearch, it just add's the new info to the database.

What I have atm is this:

```
<form action="<?php if($_GET['id']){
echo 'update.php?id='.$_GET['id'];
} Else {
echo 'insert.php';
} ?>" method="post">
```

However this returns me a nice "Undefined index: id" ;)

Any words of advice?

Comment: use `isset($_GET['id'])`

Comment: Yes: use an `isset()` in your if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first check if it's set:

```
<form action="<?php echo (isset($_GET['id'])) ? 'update.php?id='.$_GET['id']; : 'insert.php'; ?>" method="post">
```

I have replaced your `if else` with a ternary operator to keep the inline code a little tidier, too.

Comment: Already got it working thanks to GBD, but thanks for your answer :)